# Disable scrolling when launching an app (Vim) inside Windows console window

Tags: windows, vim, cmd.exe

In Windows, when I'm using the command prompt and launch Vim, I have a habit of trying to scroll through files using the mouse-wheel (which of course works in gVim but not inside the terminal).

Is there a way to configure the Windows command prompt to automatically disable scrolling (with both the scrollbar and the mousewheel) whenever an application is launched that runs inside the console window itself?

Ideally, there should be a way to have Windows "intelligently" determine whether scrolling should be disabled (since some applications, such as `ssh`, benefit from having scrolling available). Failing that, since Vim is the only application I use that behaves poorly when I try to scroll within it, I'd like to be able to just specify that launching Vim should always disable scrolling.

Comment: `set mouse=a`  ??   `:help mouse` in Vim

Comment: @lornix Nope, that's inside Vim and controls how Vim responds to scrolling.

Comment: Your question makes it difficult to determine whether you're looking to disable vim scrolling, or disable the terminal window scrolling.  Not that 'cmd.exe' is much of a terminal to begin with.  Have you looked at the `cmd.exe` command line options?  `cmd /?` ?

Comment: I said "configure the Windows command prompt to automatically disable scrolling," and that's what I meant. And yes, I realize `cmd.exe` is a lousy terminal (to be charitable), but it turns out it actually does support precisely the feature I wanted; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `cmd.exe` *does* intelligently disable scrolling by default, actually; my problem was that I was inside an `ssh` session, so Windows didn't actually know I was running `vim`. (I doubt there's a way to make the scrollbar disappear when you launch `vim` inside an `ssh` session inside `cmd.exe`.)