# Enable Scroll Wheel to scroll command prompt while it's running applications

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, scrolling, mouse-wheel

*Short summary of beneficial problem solving experience:*
After using gdb I wanted the `cmd.exe` window to scroll with the wheel of the mouse while debugging; and after finally reading:

---

[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/774269/996335) by @KyleStrand:

> Apparently `cmd.exe` does intelligently disable scrolling by default,

to this part of his question:

> Is there a way to configure the Windows command prompt to automatically
>   disable scrolling (with both the scrollbar and the mousewheel) whenever an
>   application is launched that runs inside the console window itself?
>
> Ideally, there should be a way to have Windows "intelligently" determine
>   whether scrolling should be disabled

---

it was evident that I hadn't caused this unwanted lack of mouse-wheel functionality. :)

**So how can this 'problem' be fixed in Windows 10?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to answer:

Note: currently running Windows 10 Home version 2004

They must have updated command prompt bc:

1.)  I was attempting to find properties in Command Prompt (I have its menu bar hidden), so after right-clicking on the window, one of the menu options is Scroll.  After clicking Scroll, my Command Prompt is scrollable all the time!

2.) It’s scrollable, especially when focused, even after closing and reopening Command Prompt; Scroll doesn’t need to be clicked on anymore.

---

Old answer is below.

---

Happily, just discovered this, you just have to take away focus from that `cmd.exe` window by either:

- clicking (give focus to) another (preferably small) window
- or clicking the desktop

and then the mouse wheel scrolls the application, my gdb, running in an unfocused `cmd.exe` window just fine. :D  (Using Windows 10 Home)

tl;dr: Giving focus to another window, or clicking the desktop, enables wheel scrolling in the now-unfocused `cmd.exe` window that has its scrolling "intelligently disabled".

---

edit: That window's scrolling will be enabled until you click/give-focus-back-to it again. :)

Comment: Just had this same problem. For some reason if you go into properties -> options and turn on Quick Edit Mode it fixes the scrolling problem.

Comment: @Aeolus: Note: running Windows 10 Home version 2004


They must have updated command prompt bc:

1.)  I was attempting to find properties in Command Prompt (I have its menu bar hidden), so after right-clicking on the window, one of the menu options is Scroll.  After clicking Scroll, my Command Prompt is scrollable all the time!

2.) It’s scrollable, especially when focused, even after closing and reopening Command Prompt.  Scroll doesn’t need to be clicked on anymore.